# android -How to include a library when gradle not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've included some dependencies to my gradle , they all works very well but it's been 3 days that one of these dependencies is not working anymore and I get error when gradle project sync is in progress and after a while I get this error :

```
    Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+
<a href="openFile:F:/AndroidStudioProjects/ezatpur/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

I don't use any proxies,  I reset android studio settings , I've tried some other projects and all of them has the same error .

the question is , How can I use this library without using dependencies ?

this is the library website :
https://github.com/koush/ion

how can I do so ?

Comment: Just add dependency compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6' in ur app gradle file. It will work, Can U post complete error what U r getting? 
  If posible post complete build.gradle code...

Answer (score 1):

Because this comment served me as an answer after so many painful hours, thanks to  A-n-v-e-s-h:

> Just add dependency compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6' in ur app gradle file. It will work.

Though, it might seem like specifying any specific version would, I did try with `2.1.7` before, it failed - could be a failure to resolve that. But the `2.1.6` above did work for me as well. Thanks to the original poster...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you: in Android Studio, click `File` -> `New` -> `Import new module` -> browse to the dependencies location.